# How can I loop this script from 1 to 50 in SPSS?

Tags: loops, spss

```
for i=1:50

DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
QUICK CLUSTER ZlnPrice ZCPUGhz ZWeightgramm ZDisplayinch ZCameraMp
  /MISSING=LISTWISE
  /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(i) MXITER(10) CONVERGE(0)
  /METHOD=KMEANS(NOUPDATE)
  /PRINT INITIAL.

end
```

I'd like to loop CLUSTER(i) from 1 to 50. How can I solve this problem? I'd like to avoid brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doupt that this makes much sense from a statistical point of view, but here you go.

Just put the procedure inside a macro loop and execute the macro call:

```
DEFINE !cluster_loop ()
!DO !i=1 !TO 50
   QUICK CLUSTER ZlnPrice ZCPUGhz ZWeightgramm ZDisplayinch ZCameraMp
  /MISSING=LISTWISE
  /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(!i) MXITER(10) CONVERGE(0)
  /METHOD=KMEANS(NOUPDATE)
  /PRINT INITIAL.
!DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.

!cluster_loop.
```